# Error "FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium. System halted", while installing Windows 7 on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox 4.3.22 on Windows 7 professional. I want to create Windows 7 Virtual Machine using Virtual Box. (My intention is to have a Windows 7 VM running for evaluating different software, so that the main windows 7 remains clean).

I have followed the steps below, but when I start the VM, I get the error "FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium. System halted"

1) Created VM. Chose "Microsoft Windows" from from "Type" dropdown and "Windows 7 (64 bit)" from the "version" drop down

2) I selected the memory space and other options from the wizard screens.

3) I selected "settings". Selected storage. From the "Controller IDE", I clicked on the "CD+" Icon. Clicked "Choose Disk" from the dialog box.

4) From the file selector dialog box, I selected .iso file of windows 7.

5) From the "Systems" options on the left hand menu, I disabled Floppy and Hard Disk options and pushed "CD/DVD" to the fisrt in the "Boot Order" list.

Can anyone please help me figure out the issue?. Please note that I have gone through all different threads in this forum, mentioning similar issue, but they all relate to different operating systems, such as Ubuntu or CentOS. My questions is specific to Windows 7

Comment: what chipset type did you choose? what controller types?

Comment: Controller Type is "PIIX4" and Chipset is "PIIX3"

Comment: try changing the controller to PIIX3?

Comment: ensure there is checked **`SETTINGS > SYSTEM > BOOT ORDER > HARD DRIVE`**